# Issue with type: street_address

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I have a loop that sends individual queries of places to the Places-API and returns their type if possible. The code works fine for most of the places, but I have realized for a lot of places I receive type: street_address.

When I manually input this search with:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/output?parameters

I receive the actual type for the place NOT street_address. Could this be due to running out my quota of queries for the day?

Thanks!

Comment: What is an actual type? Can you show examples of requests where we could see the difference?

Comment: If you run out of the quota the response will have status OVER_QUERY_LIMIT, you won't receive any result back.